# Android Studio 3.2 cannot resolve symbols in the layout

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I've just updated my Android Studio to 3.2 version. In my html layout I see that some ids are red and message is `cannot resolve symbol '@id/...`

[image]

As you can see at the picture, element with the not resolved id is declared just above. App builds without any problem.

Any ideas about fix?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I have found to deal with this is to close the project and re-import it.

```
File -> Close Project
Import Project(Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)
```

This bug drives me absolutely insane. I hope this helps someone else!